# Holonomy vector of saddle connection

Tags: differential-geometry, holonomy

I have a translation surface of genus 2 and I know that it has a single zero of order 2 given by the differential form $\omega = 3z^2dz$ and a total angle is $6\pi$ by turning around this point. So I wanna find a holonomy vector of saddles connection. Do I understand correctly that I should just calculate this integral $ \int_{0}^{6\pi} 3z^2dz ?$